# Website Redirecting to Welcome Codignator Page

Tags: php, html, cpanel-xmlapi

Guys I need help I have hosted the website on Ipage Server. I have uploaded the PHP development of the website and extracted the same. Have also created a copy of the Controller files outside the applications folder. But there is a issue here. Whenever I try to view my website in browser-> www.example.com it redirects me to the below page .

====

## CODING

Welcome to CodeIgniter!
The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.

If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:

application/views/welcome_message.php
The corresponding controller for this page is found at:

application/controllers/welcome.php
If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the User Guide.

## Page rendered in 0.0133 second

And I am able to see my website only when i try to view as -> www.example.com/index.php/Home .... [Home is the name of my website controller]

Comment: You need to set routes in app/Config/route.php further, you can see http://naveedramzan.com/codeigniter-url-rewriting/

Comment: There area two reserved routes:
|
| $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
| $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "Home";
$route['404_override'] = '';


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */      "404 Page cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application/config/routes.php` and set your default controller. By default it's "welcome" controller

change

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = "your_controller_name"; // home
```

Comment: There area two reserved routes:
|
| $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
| $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */  where to change ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside application/config/routes.php, set your controller name to default controller.

$route['default_controller'] = "put your controller name";